# addTextChangedListener shows response from web service more than one

Tags: android, listview-adapter

When i enter >= 3 characters inside my EditText a request is sent to my webservice and return matching content. However, when i enter more than 3 characters the list gets updated but elements are shown 2 times,3 times etc. I clear the arraylist everytime but result still wrong. Can you tell me what is wrong please. Here is the addTextChangedListener.

```
etRec.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                text_for_search = etRec.getText().toString();
                if (etRec.getText().length()>=3){

                    if (destinataire!=null)
                        destinataire.clear();

                    if (infodata!=null)
                        infodata.clear();

                    //check internet connection
                    if (Util.haveNetworkConnection(m)==true){

                        new loadingTask().execute();

                    }else {

                        InternetConnectionDialog.button_text=m.getResources().getString(R.string.recommencer_en);
                        m.startActivity(new Intent(m, InternetConnectionDialog.class));
                    }

                }}});
```

Comment: If you could show a picture or explain more your problem, it would be great :)

Comment: when i enter text greater than 3 message are displayed more than once

Comment: BUt what is this message? A toast?, a list?, just a String?, maybe everytime you enter a character the webservice is launched and you dont clean the previous results.

Comment: i cleaned the previous result  using    destinataire.clear();